# C, FIFO queue, client-server application

Tags: c

The goal of the task is to write a client-server application that calculates the sum of various NxN elements. Separately enabled servers are supposed to calculate successive rows of a two-dimensional array and return them to the client, which will calculate the grand sum. My problem is related to receiving these values from the server. The server calculates the sum of the numbers correctly, but when displaying the given sum in the client, the values are either 0 or a very low negative number.

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define N 3
#define FIFO_PATH "fifo_channel"

int main() {
    int server_fds[N]; 
    int i, j;
    int array[N][N] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}; 

    mkfifo(FIFO_PATH, 0666);

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        char fifo_name[20];
        sprintf(fifo_name, "%s%d", FIFO_PATH, i);
        server_fds[i] = open(fifo_name, O_WRONLY);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        write(server_fds[i], array[i], sizeof(int) * N);
    }

    int partial_sums[N];
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        read(server_fds[i], &partial_sums[i], sizeof(int));
    }

    int total_sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        total_sum += partial_sums[i];
    }

    printf("Suma całkowita: %d\n", total_sum);

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        close(server_fds[i]);
    }

    unlink(FIFO_PATH);

    return 0;
}
```

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define N 3 
#define FIFO_PATH "fifo_channel"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int server_id = atoi(argv[1]); 
    int client_fd;
    int array[N];

    char fifo_name[20];
    sprintf(fifo_name, "%s%d", FIFO_PATH, server_id);
    client_fd = open(fifo_name, O_RDONLY);

    read(client_fd, array, sizeof(int) * N);

    int partial_sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        partial_sum += array[i];
    }

    write(client_fd, &partial_sum, sizeof(int));

    close(client_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

I know O_WRONLY makes us open for write only, so I tried to re-enclose the same loop as above only opening in read mode

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    char fifo_name[20];
    sprintf(fifo_name, "%s%d", FIFO_PATH, i);
    server_fds[i] = open(fifo_name, O_RDONLY);
}
```

after that the program displayed two variables (also wrongly calculated) and then it crashed.